# How can upload a large dataset to Github

Tags: git, github

I need to add dataset containing images to Github. But github says file too large

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: How large a dataset in MB or GB?

Answer (score 1):

To upload large files, refer to [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/). The page has the instructions of its usage.

Answer (score -1):

If you accidentally commit files with more than 100MB in your area, you will have a hard time trying to press them on GitHub. Cannot be solved by deleting large files and committing them again. This is because GitHub tracks all commitments, not just the latest. Technically you press files across your entire commitment record.
While you can technically fix it by installing a branch, it is not a straightforward thing. Fortunately, you can use a repository cleaner and it automatically cleans every large file that is created.
Download BFG Repo-Cleaner bfg.jar and apply the following command:
Java -jar bfg.jar - Strip-blobs-larger-than-100M <your_repo>
It automatically cleans up your performance and generates a new commit with the words 'delete large files'. Push and get ready to go.